# How to make a call to Telephone by TAPI?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, tapi

I need to design an API that enables phone number, when clicked, make a call via TAPI system. How should it be achieved via Programming?

I am using CakePHP application. Also, the user needs to enable Call in Desktops, mobile and Tablets. Is there any apis available for such Interfacing?

I tried using:

```
<a href="tel:8005550199">Call 800-555-0199</a>
```

But I got the following error in firefox:

```
The address wasn't understood

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (tel) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.
```

Comment: Why vote down and close?!

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

TAPI is not an applicable technology here. It is only available to Windows desktop applications, and can only be used there to control voice modems and PBX systems. As such, it is **not** usable even on most Windows desktop systems, as they are not connected to the appropriate phone hardware. It is certainly not usable in a web page, or in a CakePHP application.

The only generally available way to initiate a telephone call from a web page is by creating a `tel:` link, e.g.

```html
<a href="tel:8005550199">Call 800-555-0199</a>
```

Keep in mind that this will still only work on devices that have some sort of access to the telephone network, either directly, e.g. on cell phones, or indirectly, e.g. via Skype or other VOIP applications.

Comment: If I have my OS installed with some TAPI system, then will the call be initiated? Can you also give some applications (say, TAPI systems), that support this call feature by using href in anchor tag? Since, I am not aware of my client system's TAPI, I would like to test the same in my local..

Comment: @duskwuff I tried your solution and got the above error(updated in question). What should be the solution then?

Comment: @sємsєм That would make the web server initiate a phone call locally, which is almost certainly not what you want. (Even if it has phone hardware connected, there is probably nobody sitting at the server to talk on it.)

Comment: @GaneshBabu.T.Y That means you don't have any software installed which can make a phone call. You'll need to install some to use a `tel:` link.